# What are the permutations of 6 different variables with multiple values?

Tags: combinatorics

*Apologies if this is better explained in another question; perhaps I'd better get up to speed with mathematics terminology so I may find it...*

There are the following 6 options for searching on a website:

- Countries: 228
- Regions: 456
- Genders: 2
- Payment: 4
- Age: 8
- Sort: 3

You can choose **zero or one** of each option per URL. Assume each country has "ownership" of two regions. A region may only be included when its parent country is selected.

**How would I begin to calculate how many possible permutations (URLs) there are here?** I've used specific online calculators but I don't think I'm inputting the correct numbers, and I've read some of the permutation questions on here but I can't seem to compare them to my own use-case.

Example URLs:
`/Australia/Actors-wanted/Females/Age-34/Paid/Sort-by-p/`
`/New-Zealand/Wellington/Actors-wanted/Sort-by-p/`

Answer (score 1):

Since you can choose zero or one countries, you have $229$ choices for country.  Similarly you have $457$ choice for region.  The number of choices for country plus region is then $229 \cdot 457=104653$  Keep multiplying to include the other options.